# slides 2 divs at the same time jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im planning on slidding 2 divs at the same time ,each one in opposite directions.How can i do this?

this is what i have tried

```
$("button").click(function () {  
    $(".cuadro").animate({ left: '250px', queue: false });
    $("#R").animate({ left: '-250px', queue: false });
});
```

also if it's possible i can this to happend when my services tab is active instead of when the person click on the button.

```
<section id="services" class="content-section text-center">
        <div class="services-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2><span class="auto-style2">Services</span></h2>
                    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                    <h2><strong>Technlogies and lenguages used for software developing<br />
                        </strong></h2>
                    <p  class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Download Resume</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <button id="serv">serv</button>


               </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <div class="cuadro" id="L"><h2 class="leng">C#</h2></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="cuadro" id="R"><h2 class="leng">JavaScript</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

this is my nav bar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabs">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page-top">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">RESUME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll"  id="serTab" href="#services">SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: `$("#R").animate({left:'-=250px'}); $("#L").animate({left:'+=250px'});` Make sure these elements are `position: absolute` or `position: relative` or `position: fixed`

Comment: @blex that worked perfectly! thanks so much. Now, can you help me making this event happening when the tab services is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();

$('#serTab').click(function(){
    $("#R").animate({left:'-=250px'}); 
    $("#L").animate({left:'+=250px'});
});
```

Note that `id="tabs"` must be moved from the `<ul>` to its parent `<div>`

---

If that doesn't work, you may need event delegation. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#serTab', function(){
    $("#R").animate({left:'-=250px'}); 
    $("#L").animate({left:'+=250px'});
});
```

Reference:

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate